# Checking if two objects have the same y-axis

Tags: android

I have been creating a simple android game, but have been encountering some problems in checking if an object falling down has passed another object on the y-axis.

This is my code:

```
//SKULLY is the object falling down
//USER is the object that SKULLY will have to pass through to add a point

 public void checkPassed()
{
    if (skullY == user.getY())
    {
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is that, when **SKULLY** passes through or is equal to the y-axis of the **USER** then it will add a single point.

When I change the condition to **>** or **<** it works perfectly fine no matter what position USER is in. But when I put it in **====** no point is added.

If you have to downvote me, please leave a comment on why was I downvoted. Thanks in advance for any help or insight on this problem! :D

Comment: How do these variables change? It it possible that they are never equal?

Comment: @Henry Oh sorry sir, I forgot to explain that user is able to move around the screen. So it's y-axis is always changing sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its sound like a Game equals ("==") almost never happens.. my Suggestion is

```
if(skullY < user.getY() && skullY > user.getY() + 10) {
   // Do Stuff here.. 

}
```

try to lower 10 as much as possible until you will get the desire result..

Comment: Sir your answer is correct. I just changed the code to this and it worked " if (skullY > user.getY() && skullY < user.getY() + 10)". I just have to wait 3 mins to accept your answer haha. Here is an upvote for the meantime, and Thanks again! :D